# AngularJS get Data from php Service in cross domain

Tags: php, angularjs

I currently have a script that checks my server information. They have provided a file called index.php - when I load this file in the URL, the content of an .xml file is generated.

My question is, how can I get data from this php file/URL in my Controller?

I use the php url in script but its not working.

**Controller.js**

```
var Factory = angular.module('Factory ', ['ngRoute']);
Factory .controller('Controller', function ($scope, $http, $route)
{
     $http.get('http://example.com/index.php')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "FALSE";
            alert("error");
        });
});
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('example.com','abc_5','gf#$6','example_db');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_getName") ||
    !$mysqli->query('CREATE PROCEDURE SP_getName() BEGIN SELECT Name from user_tbl END;')) {
    echo "Stored procedure creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
$result = $mysqli->query("CALL SP_getName()");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}
print(json_encode($output));
?>
```

I try to call the data from the service, I get nothing. I understand that the query is asynchronous but I am having a hard time understanding how to populate the $scope variable once the data is returned.

Comment: Is there an error message resulting from the ajax call? Or is the issue with the php script?  If you have the php script just echo out a string, will you get the same issue?

Comment: Can you speak to your CORS configuration?

Comment: if you have to cross the domains, y dont you use a reverse proxy in your server

Comment: did you host your angular page in the same server as index.php?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have to add the following to your headers in PHP:

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS